# Running a long PHP script on cloudflare gives me a timeout (using nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, timeout, cloudflare

I am using nginx + cloudflare. I run a long php script that should take like 1-2 mins before it completes and redirect on another page. After completely running, cloudflare gives me a timeout occured. Here are my current settings on nginx.conf;

```
client_body_timeout 12;
client_header_timeout 12;
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
client_max_body_size 8m;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
keepalive_timeout 15;
send_timeout 10;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
```

and my php.ini already has `max_execution_time` set to 300;

What am I missing here and what can I do to make cloudflare be able to run this php script without my server timing out in the process?

Comment: what is the error number on cloudflare?

Comment: @ClearBoth Error: 524 A timeout occurred.

Comment: Cloudflare responds to the request within 90 seconds after that it will gave up and send the error 524. Even if you set the execution time to 300 in your website, it does not matter as Cloudflare will not longer than 90 seconds. The solution maybe is to start increase the performance of your script. more than 90 seconds actually is too long for normal script. See also: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out

Comment: @ClearBoth thanks for that. The php script runs curl and mysql, so i'm thinking maybe it's in there. I'll just try to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I worked around this kind of issue by doing multiple redirects:

- request comes in to URL - start background job
- after 60 seconds redirect to URL?stage=2
- after 60 seconds redirect to URL?stage=3
- ...
- while job is running, every 60 seconds redirect to URL?stage=N
- when job is finished redirect to final url

Though I wasn't using PHP and Nginx so not sure if this is applicable to you too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to redirect to stages, as @Andrejs wrote.
Other scenario could be:

- start main script with function ignore_user_abort(true) . This do not cancel script when http timeouts. When script is done, insert row in database or create some file.
- On frontend make periodical ajax calls while on server side new database record appeared or created new file.
- If you detect that operation is finished, redirect user to download file or show something info.